# Remove underline in nested element whose parent element is underlined?

Tags: css, html

```html
<p style="text-decoration: underline;">Click Me<sup style="text-decoration: none;">?</sup></p>
```

I'm trying to nest an element in an element that has an underline property but remove that property for the nested element. It's not working, the `?` remains underlined in this scenario and adding `!important` does not help.

Edit: The actual elements are in an abbreviation:

```
<tr>
  <th class="text-center" "text-decoration: underline;"><abbr title="Due Monthly" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Actions<sup>?</sup></abbr></th>
</tr>
```

So I can't have sup be outside of th as it is invalid in tr.

Comment: You going to have to un-nest that element for this to work. Is there any reason the question mark needs to be nested?

Comment: Yes these are table headers, so I don't want to remove the `sup` from the table header as it should have the same clickable properties as the table header.

Comment: @DaFois I did post the css, it's inline...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child elements style won't change the parent element's.

You could do something like this:

```
<p>
    <span class="underline">Click Me</span>
    <span>?</span>
</p>
```

Comment: So I should nest the previous parent element and child element as siblings into another parent?

Comment: @ZacharySchwatz Yes. Just in case it isn't clear: the <sup> in your example isn't underlined; you're simply looking at the underline of the <p>. And the styles on the <sup> can't affect the <p>.

Comment: This solution does not work for my situation see edit.

Comment: It should work if you create another element around "Actions" and put the underline style on that element.

Comment: what element, it's in an abbr element and p, div are invalid. `<sup>` is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Taking the <sup> out of its parent works the same way no matter what the parent is, be it an <abbr> or a <p>.

Comment: @MrLister Its parent now is a table header... If I take it out of that it will be in a table row, which is invalid html...

Comment: It looks like your sup element is inside the abbr element. Take it out so the parent of both the abbr element and the sup element are in the th element. The underline styling can't be on the th element for this to work. It needs to be on a child element if you only want some of the elements in the th to be displayed with an underline.

Comment: Yeah thanks that works, that's actually what I did and came back and saw this. It's going to mean a lot of style tags.